# iCloud-enabled Mac app is unable to connect to CloudKit server

Tags: networking, macos, mac, icloud

I'm developing a macOS app using Apple's CloudKit technology and have received an error report from one particular user who is unable to synchronize data with Apple's iCloud server because of a "Network Unavailable" error. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with his network configuration because I don't see anything from his client in my iCloud log files and it only happens for this particular user. We want to track down the problem and have already tried the following steps:

- The user has LittleSnitch installed and turned the network filter off temporarily without any difference
- The user cannot ping Apple's CloudKit server:

  ```
  ping -c4 p61-ckdatabase.icloud.com:443
  ping: cannot resolve p61-ckdatabase.icloud.com:443: Unknown host
  ```
- Synchronization in Apple Notes (which also uses CloudKit) works fine
- The issue persists when he connects his Mac to an iPhone hotspot

The following messages appear in the system log while starting the app:

```
problem 15:10:44.020090 +0200   cfprefsd    attempt to write to a container /var/root/Library/Group Containers/7T8DYS43CJ.de.lisczyk.felix.SnipNotes that does not yet exist. Using client-provided container path without resolving symlinks.
fehler  15:10:44.020238 +0200   SnipNotes   Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6180000fe580> (Domain: 7T8DYS43CJ.de.lisczyk.felix.SnipNotes, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null)): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
standard    15:10:44.321589 +0200   SnipNotes   [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.4 (121)
standard    15:10:44.436198 +0200   SnipNotes   Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
standard    15:10:44.436230 +0200   SnipNotes   Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
standard    15:10:44.436253 +0200   SnipNotes   Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
standard    15:10:44.475833 +0200   SnipNotes   0x61000046e100 opened /var/folders/2r/_94bykls11dbzf_71qwcc47r0000gp/C/de.lisczyk.felix.SnipNotesMacApp//mds/mdsObject.db: 4636 bytes
standard    15:10:44.476194 +0200   SnipNotes   0x61800046ba00 opened /var/folders/2r/_94bykls11dbzf_71qwcc47r0000gp/C/de.lisczyk.felix.SnipNotesMacApp//mds/mdsDirectory.db: 50744 bytes
standard    15:10:44.477688 +0200   SnipNotes   0x61000046e100 opened /var/folders/2r/_94bykls11dbzf_71qwcc47r0000gp/C/de.lisczyk.felix.SnipNotesMacApp//mds/mdsDirectory.db: 50744 bytes
standard    15:10:44.479548 +0200   SnipNotes   0x608000c60180 opened /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db: 344032 bytes
standard    15:10:44.483240 +0200   SnipNotes   0x608000c60500 opened /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates: 25604 bytes
standard    15:10:44.485988 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.486137 +0200   SnipNotes   0x600001874e00 opened /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates: 31108 bytes
standard    15:10:44.489005 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.489110 +0200   SnipNotes   0x61000046f5c0 opened /Library/Keychains/System.keychain: 163852 bytes
standard    15:10:44.491864 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.491965 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.492204 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.492360 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.492548 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.492670 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.492879 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.492983 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.493224 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.493317 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.493628 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.493755 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.493995 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.494104 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.494338 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.494438 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.494674 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.494801 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.495032 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Start [1:0x618000381110]
standard    15:10:44.495793 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.495933 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.496195 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.496298 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.496605 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.496723 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.497016 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.497146 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.497395 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.497530 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.497785 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.497880 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.498038 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Start [2:0x60800019e6b0]
standard    15:10:44.679542 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Event [1:0x618000381110]: 1 Err(0)
standard    15:10:44.679567 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Connected [1:0x618000381110]: Err(0)
standard    15:10:44.679687 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC Enabling TLS [1:0x618000381110]
standard    15:10:44.680485 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Event [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 1 Err(0)
standard    15:10:44.680510 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Connected [2:0x60800019e6b0]: Err(0)
standard    15:10:44.680690 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC Enabling TLS [2:0x60800019e6b0]
standard    15:10:44.825914 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [1:0x618000381110]: 2, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.829242 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [1:0x618000381110]: 11, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.830154 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [1:0x618000381110]: 12, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.830214 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [1:0x618000381110]: 14, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.831864 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 2, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.834275 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Trust Result [1:0x618000381110]: 0
standard    15:10:44.834397 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 11, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.837836 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 12, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.837882 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 14, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.842192 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Trust Result [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 0
standard    15:10:44.959226 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [1:0x618000381110]: 20, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.959586 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Event [1:0x618000381110]: 8 Err(0)
standard    15:10:44.959619 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Handshake Complete [1:0x618000381110]
standard    15:10:44.960159 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.960309 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.960739 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.960976 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.961243 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.961423 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.961683 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.961795 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.962831 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.962977 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.963267 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.963430 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.963751 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.963947 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.964021 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Event [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 20, Pending(0)
standard    15:10:44.964297 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.964330 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Event [2:0x60800019e6b0]: 8 Err(0)
standard    15:10:44.964356 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TLS Handshake Complete [2:0x60800019e6b0]
standard    15:10:44.964496 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.964794 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.964914 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.965168 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.965316 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.965767 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.965969 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.966246 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.966379 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.966724 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.966888 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.967214 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.967405 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.967743 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.967853 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.968149 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
standard    15:10:44.968322 +0200   SnipNotes   skipping upgrade for locked keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
standard    15:10:45.130344 +0200   SnipNotes   TIC TCP Conn Cancel [1:0x618000381110]
standard    15:10:46.587492 +0200   SnipNotes Helper    Performance: Please update this scripting addition to supply a value for ThreadSafe for each event handler: "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax"
```

I would appreciate any advice you could give me on how to isolate the issue. Thank you!